# Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler

I tried to run a scheduled task in my Spring-Boot application, using the default `applicationConfig` - I only added the annotation `@EnableScheduling` and configured the class with the method that is to be scheduled, per the following code sample:

```
@Component 
public class Task { 

 @Scheduled(cron ="*/10 * * * * *")
  public void init() {
    System.out.println("QuartzConfig initialized.");
    System.out.println(callService());
  }

  private String callService() {
    String urlService = "https://www.google.com";
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(urlService );
    String response = "";
    try {
        client.executeMethod(method);
        response = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        method.releaseConnection();
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

However, when the task is called, the method `callService` returns the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

This, quite obviously, makes me sad.

Comment: Which line is the exception coming from? The most obvious culprit is that client == null. Where does client get set?

Comment: yes @edgarNgwenya now test added the init method of client and run well thanks for you point.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments I solved this added next code to init method

```
 public Task(){     
          client = new HttpClient();
          client.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "Bacon/1.0");
    }
```

thanks to @edgarNgwenya